# WP Product Page Help needed

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I'm trying to make this product page and have the items all in there but the problem is the pictures for each item are different size. I tried using Hard Crop but it didn't work.

I want the best solution for this that takes up the least amount of time and is the easiest.

http://burnabycitycomputers.com/shop

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Comment: What are you aiming to do?

Comment: Please show the code that you already have. Highlight the piece of your code that is producing a different result from what you want. State explicitly what you expected and what it is producing instead.

Comment: You can look at the shop page and see the problem, the products are not lined up properly because of their size. I want all of them to be lined up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change the style to the woocommerce.css file in line no.48

```
.woocommerce .page-wrapper img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> Add this style to your style.css file

```
.woocommerce .t-entry-visual {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If no tricks worked out put an **!important** over to your css and this should make a trick for you. I have not used important if needed you pursue that.

[image]

Comment: No need for cropping the images. You can control it over to the Style-sheet Itself and it the very easiest method of doing. :)

Comment: Cool:) Rock on ... Glad to help you.